# On input radio change disable all elements from sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with two sections that I want to disable each one when the other is enabled. A kind of toggle between them.
For example if radio from first section is selected than all elements (:input) from section two will be disabled and vice versa.

I have created this but is not really working because the element variable is not targeting in the right way something like (this).

```
var variab = ('.radio-input');
$('.form-horizontal').on('change', variab, function() {

    var element = $('.well :input').not('.radio-input');
    var el = $(this).closest('.radioOption').find(element);

    element.prop('disabled', function() { 
        return !el.is(this);
    })
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6034/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

First assign same name to all radio button for `class="radio-input"` so that only one radio button can be selected at a time. Lets say `name="radio-input"` like below :

```
<input type="radio" class="radio-input" name="radio-input"/>
```

Then use this jQuery :

```
var variab = ('.radio-input');
    $('.form-horizontal').on('change', variab, function() {
    // disable all input under .well div except radio button
    $(this).parents('.well').siblings().find(':input').not('.radio-input').prop('disabled', true);
     // enable all input under .well div for current radio button selected.
        $(this).parents('.well').find(':input').prop('disabled', false);

    });
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6046/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using this code, you need to assign same name to your radio option

```
(function(){
  $(".radio-input").on("change", function() {
      var clicked = $(this).closest(".well")
      var other = $(".well").not(clicked);
      clicked.find("input[type='text']").prop("disabled", false); 
      other.find("input[type='text']").prop("disabled", true);

  })
}());
```

A working example [here](http://jsbin.com/bezeruro/1/edit)